# Autossh is not working the same locally than on a remote server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, autossh

If I start `autossh` on my local machine as follow:

```bsh
autossh -M 20000 -f - nNT -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B
```

it automatically launches the following `ssh` command under the hood, which is what I expect:

```bsh
ps aux | grep -i ssh
/usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 20000 -f - nNT -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server
/usr/bin/ssh -L 20000:127.0.0.1:20000 -R 20000:127.0.0.1:20001 -N -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B
```

but the same command launched on a remote server A only shows this with `ps`:

```bsh
/usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 20000 -f - nNT -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B
```

it seems it didn't started the underlying `ssh` command.

(please note that if I start the `ssh` command manually on the remote server A, I can properly connect to the remote server B then.)

I cannot figure out why the command behaves differently on the remote than on my local computer...

Both `autossh` versions are `1.4g` on my local computer and on the remote server A.

And both machines are on Ubuntu 20.04.

**EDIT**:

Per Stéphane Chazelas' comment: I actually notice two slightly different behaviors when trying the command on two different remote machines:

1.

```bsh
$ strace -fe execve autossh -M 20000  -f  -nNT -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B
execve("/usr/bin/autossh", ["autossh", "-M", "20000", "-f", "-nNT", "-L", "192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432", "remote-user@remote-server-B"], 0x7fff532c2f68 /* 40 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 23539 attached
[pid 23539] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=23539, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 23540 attached
[pid 23540] execve("/bin/egrep", ["egrep", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b83714eae8 /* 38 vars */) = 0
[pid 23540] execve("/home/username/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/home/username/.local/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/home/username/anaconda3/condabin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/opt/blenderc/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/usr/local/sbin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/usr/local/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/usr/sbin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/usr/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/sbin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 23540] execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55b692ae0a28 /* 38 vars */) = 0
[pid 23540] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=23540, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
execve("/usr/lib/autossh/autossh", ["/usr/lib/autossh/autossh", "-M", "20000", "-f", "-nNT", "-L", "192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432", "remote-user@remote-server-B"], 0x55b83714f470 /* 38 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 23541 attached
[pid 23538] +++ exited with 0 +++
strace: Process 23542 attached
[pid 23542] execve("/usr/bin/ssh", ["/usr/bin/ssh", "-L", "20000:127.0.0.1:20000", "-R", "20000:127.0.0.1:20001", "-nNT", "-L", "192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432", "remote-user@remote-server-B"], 0x7ffce7ca53e0 /* 38 vars */) = 0
[pid 23542] +++ exited with 255 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=23542, si_uid=1000, si_status=255, si_utime=2, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 23543 attached
[pid 23543] execve("/usr/bin/ssh", ["/usr/bin/ssh", "-L", "20000:127.0.0.1:20000", "-R", "20000:127.0.0.1:20001", "-nNT", "-L", "192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432", "remote-user@remote-server-B"], 0x7ffce7ca53e0 /* 38 vars */) = 0
```

(the last 3 lines being repeated infinitely at regular interval, each time with a different process ID)

2.

```bsh
$ strace -fe execve autossh -M 20000  -f  -nNT -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B
execve("/usr/bin/autossh", ["autossh", "-M", "20000", "-f", "-nNT", "-L", "192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432", "remote-user@remote-server-B"], 0x7fff7be64dc8 /* 34 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 3850 attached
[pid  3850] +++ exited with 0 +++
strace: Process 3851 attached
[pid  3849] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3850, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid  3851] execve("/bin/egrep", ["egrep", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x55690bd42a08 /* 32 vars */) = 0
[pid  3851] execve("/usr/local/sbin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x5637ad7d9958 /* 32 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3851] execve("/usr/local/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x5637ad7d9958 /* 32 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3851] execve("/usr/sbin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x5637ad7d9958 /* 32 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3851] execve("/usr/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x5637ad7d9958 /* 32 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3851] execve("/sbin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x5637ad7d9958 /* 32 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3851] execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "-E", "-q", "--", "-f?M ?[0-9]+"], 0x5637ad7d9958 /* 32 vars */) = 0
[pid  3851] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3851, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
execve("/usr/lib/autossh/autossh", ["/usr/lib/autossh/autossh", "-M", "20000", "-f", "-nNT", "-L", "192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432", "remote-user@remote-server-B"], 0x55690bd433a0 /* 32 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 3852 attached
[pid  3849] +++ exited with 0 +++
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

(and then it immediately returns the console to the user)

Comment: Try with `strace -fe execve autossh....` to see what it *tries* to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I  figured out the tiny difference which occurred when using `autossh` on a remote machine versus on my local machine.

On the latter computer, I was prompted by a GUI popup to enter the passphrase for the ssh key I am using to connect to the remote server B.

This passphrase prompt never happened when using `autossh` on any remote machine to connect to the same server B, because, well, there is not GUI there (headless server) (but it naturally does prompt for the passphrase when you make use of `ssh` itself).

Therefore, I have to let my terminal know about the key passphrase prior to running `autossh`. You can do that, e.g. using `ssh-agent` inside the running terminal before launching `autossh`. And then it suddenly works.

#### Detailed solution

This solution is given as an example.

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file before sourcing it (or reopening a terminal):

```bsh
ssh-eval() {
   eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add "${1}"
}

export -f ssh-eval
```

then run:

```bsh
ssh-eval ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key
```

Enter the corresponding **passphrase**! This was the missing part for `autossh` to actually work!

Run `autossh` with a monitor port that is **not** already used on the remote!

```bsh
autossh -M 20002 -f - nNT -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B
```

As port `20000` was used by my local computer, it couldn't connect when using the same port from another machine. You can only know that by running the corresponding `ssh` command itself, e.g.:

```bsh
$ ssh -L 20000:127.0.0.1:20000 -R 20000:127.0.0.1:20001 -N -L 192.168.144.1:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 remote-user@remote-server-B

Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/your_ssh_key': 
****

Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 20000
```

Also beware that your local port is not already used, otherwise you'll face something like this:

```bsh
...
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5433
```

Last but not least, do not "blindly" increase the monitor port by only +1 as:

> -M port[:echo_port]
>
> specifies the base monitoring port to use. Without the echo port, this
> port and the port immediately above it ( port + 1) should be something
> nothing else is using. autossh will send test data on the base
> monitoring port, and receive it back on the port above. For example,
> if you specify "-M 20000", autossh will set up forwards so that it can
> send data on port 20000 and receive it back on 20001.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh